# host solr cloud on multiple machines

Tags: solr, solrcloud

Is there any way so that we can host solr cloud on multiple machine's?.
lets say we have 1000 collections & upon which i want 500 collections on machine 1 and next 500 collections on machine 2.
If we did such a set up how can we can route specific indexing & searching requests to specific machines?
I found zookeeper configuration after researching on this problem, but does not understand how to done it.

Comment: Try reading something like https://medium.com/@sarkaramrit2/setting-up-solr-cloud-6-3-0-with-zookeeper-3-4-6-867b96ec4272 . - it's quite straightforward - setup a ZooKeeper ensemble (at least 3 nodes), start multiple Solr on multiple machines each pointing back to the ZooKeeper ensemble.

Comment: BTW each collection on Solr requires a lot of heap - with 4GB of RAM we found we ran out of heap with about 100 collections - regardless of the amount of data in each collection.